# Kendo MultiSelect Cannot read property 'value'

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

It is my PartialView:

```
.......

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.securities, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">

       @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
         .Name("productMultiSelect")
         .DataTextField("label")
         .DataValueField("value")Product to be used by the multiselect as a value.
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:350px; height:350px", @id = "prd" })
         .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
        .DataSource(source =>
         {
             source.Read(read =>
             {
                 read.Action("GetLogin", "IT_Inventory");
             })
             .ServerFiltering(false);
         })
        .Value(ViewBag.SelectedItem2)
        .ItemTemplate("<span><h3 style=\"font-size: 1.2em;font-weight: normal;margin: 0 0 1px 0;padding: 0;\">#: data.label #</h3><p style=\"margin:0;padding:0;font-size: .8em; \">#: data.desc #</p></span>")  
                )
            </div>
        </div>
```

My button:

```
<button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Save </button>
```

My JS:

```
<script>
    $("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventdefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("SignIT", "IT_Inventory")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ productMultiSelect: $("#productMultiSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(), id: $("#id").val(), SomeBooleanProperty: false }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == true) {
                    $("#onInsert").data("kendoWindow").close();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An error has occured!!!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I try post to controller I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. For id and SomeBooleanProperty is ok.
When I use submit form is ok.
I should post data to controller list of productMultiSelect?

Comment: try wrapping your js function into `.ready()`. Might be, that listener is added before multiselect is initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you havn't initialize you kendoMultiSelect, or it's in another div;

Check to see it:

```
console.log($("#productMultiSelect").length); //should be at least 1, if 0, then you initialized kendo in come other div
```

and

```
console.log($("#productMultiSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect")); //should be an object - if undefined, then you have not initialized kendo
```

Comment: Thanks. My MultiSelect id is "prd".

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($("#productMultiSelect").length); - 0
console.log($("#productMultiSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect")); - undefined
```

very interesting and strange.

This PartialView is in KendoWindow.